# How to access Application class variables in activity in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

- I used to access application class private variables by using a
  public methods in java
- How to do the same using kotlin

**App.kt**

```
class App : Application() {


    private var app: App? = null
    private var movieAppComponent: MovieAppComponent? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        app = this

        movieAppComponent = DaggerMovieAppComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .netModule(NetModule(Keys.BASE_URL, this))
            .build()
    }

    fun getApp(): App? {
        return app
    }

    fun getMovieAppComponent(): MovieAppComponent? {
        return movieAppComponent
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        App.getApp().getMovieAppComponent().inject(this)
    }



}
```

**Error:**

```
App.getApp().getMovieAppComponent().inject(this)
```

Here `getApp()` i am getting as unresolved reference

Comment: Because `getApp` is a non static method .. make `app` static with Companion block ..

Comment: @ADM .... can u show it as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
class App : Application() {

    private var movieAppComponent: MovieAppComponent? = null

    companion object {
        private var app: App? = null

        fun getApp(): App? {
            return app
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        app = this

        movieAppComponent = DaggerMovieAppComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .netModule(NetModule(Keys.BASE_URL, this))
            .build()
    }

    fun getMovieAppComponent(): MovieAppComponent? {
        return movieAppComponent
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

No need to create such method. You can use type casting in your Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        (application as? App)?.getMovieAppComponent()?.inject(this)
    }
}
```